# Referencing Packages in Java

Tags: java, netbeans, reference, package

I am in project/package A and need to create an object from project/package B for unit tests. The problem is that package B references package A's jar files. I can't reference package B from package A without creating a circular dependency. I am unable to change the location of any files. How do I create/reference the object class from package B?

Comment: Looks like you need a common jar called C which will be referenced in both A and B.

Comment: Circular dependencies across Java packages won't break anything. Mechanically it's just fine.

Comment: @user1676075 if project A needs Project B to builds and Project B needs project A to build how would you go  on building them ?

Comment: @StackFlowed but the question says "unable to change the location of any files" which implies creating a 3rd jar from the common pieces is not an option. If combining into one project is an option, that works. If factoring into a 3rd (common) jar is an option, that works. I suppose the other question is "if A doesn't already reference B, why would you possibly need to create an object from B for a unit test?"

Comment: My guess is perhaps A has an interface that B implements, and OP wants an implementation to test against. The correct answer, then, would to instead use a mock object, something like Mockito, in A to create a mock of the interface and thus never have to reference B.